# I can't preview some layouts with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have some troubles with my Android Studio IDE, the problem is that I can't preview some of my layouts inside the design mode or the preview window.
the strange thing is that there is no "API version Editor" in the list :

[image]

I tried Clean/build my project, Invalidate and restart the IDE but the problem stills there .

Have you ever get this issus with Android Studio ? 
My Android Studio infos :

[image]

Regards

Comment: open sdk-manager and download some.

Comment: update your sdk

Answer (score 1):

Just press "Sync Project with gradle" and voila! your layout preview is right there... Sync icon is present in the toolbar

[image: Sync Project with gradle]

or Go to  **FILE** Menu -> **Sync Projects with Gradle files.**

Comment: didn't work for me, I tried many times, the Sync is OK but not the preview

Comment: then try downloading the system image of the API version you are working with.. via the Android - > SDK Manager  and also check in the  `build.gradle(Module:app)` file check your `minSdkVersion` and make it **17**